# Fermats little theorem:

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Showing there are infinitely many primes in the form : $6k+5$. 
I have solved by contradiction.

I think I was suppose to solve it using Fermat's Little Theorem. I do not understand the F.L.T.

Comment: Please explain your proof by contradiction.

Comment: What makes you think you were supposed to solve the problem using Fermat?

Comment: So I am trying to find a general way to solve 6k+1 and others. But proofs by contradictions fail in 4k+1  and 6k+1 and many others. it works for 4k+3.

Comment: While this won't help prove it, this is a consequence of [Dirichlet's Theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

Comment: I don't know the trick in 6k+1 and I believe F.L.T always works.

Comment: I do not know a proof by FLT, but I think the approach suggested by you is correct.

Comment: Is there a way I can use generally to solve all problems like this ? Generalize for all ?

Comment: [This paper](https://lup.lub.lu.se/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=5042097&fileOId=5042100) discusses it some, but only shows how to do it for $nk+1$ via Fermat's little theorem

Comment: Ah it's something like that I needed, thanks Mark!  

Do you suppose it changes much for problems like 6k+5 and others 4k+3?
Is it wrong to believe that Fermat's Little Theorem will work for all problems like this. That is the impression I am getting based on how fondly the professor speaks of Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: Isn't this the same "question" as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486855/fermats-little-theorem-documents?

Comment: Why do you believe Fermat always works? The way to prove the general theorem, Dirichlet's Theorem that @Mark refers to, uses stuff way beyond Fermat.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose that there are finitely many primes of the form $6k+5$, namely 
$p_1,\cdots, p_n$.

Consider 
$p'=6p_1\cdots p_n -1$.

Comment: Nooo I don't need to know how to prove it. I have a proof already. I am wondering about Fermat's Little Theorem. My approach was confirmed as correct this is why I deleted my comment to drift focus back to Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: I have it proved using this method. I need help using Fermat's Little Theorem .